# If $V\cong W$ and $U\subseteq V$, is $U\cong T(U)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

In linear algebra, I’ve just shown that $V\cong V’’$, ie $V$ is isomorphic to its double dual.

I now want to show that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ then $U$ is mapped isomorphically to $U^{00}$, ie the annihilator of the annihilator of $U$.

If $T:V\to V’’$ is the natural isomorphism, how can I show that $U\cong T(U)$?

Because I know $T(U)\subseteq U^{00}$, so I will be done.

Comment: If $\psi \colon V \to W$ is an isomorphism and $U$ a subspace of $V$, then $\psi(U) \cong U$ because the restriction $\psi\colon U \to \psi(U)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @azif00 Why is the restriction an isomorphism? Is it because a restriction of a linear bijection remains a linear bijection ?

Comment: Yes. Or just note that if $\psi \colon V \to W$ is injective, then $\psi|_U \colon U \to W$ is also injective and has image $\psi(U)$.